# Wordpress plugin activation creating table

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am trying to create a table with my wordpress plugin on activation. I have this and it is not working:

```
function activate_cron() {
    global $wpdb;

    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "fbcron";

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE ".$table_name." (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    post_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    ) ".$charset_collate.";";

    require_once( '../../../wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta($sql);
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'activate_cron' );
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? is there any error that you can tell us?

Answer (score 0):

I believe for dbDelta the collate  needs to be on its own line. It can be easier to make sure you have the right spacing by embedding the variables in the string:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE {$table_name} (
id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
post_id int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (id)
) 
{$charset_collate};";
```

Comment: although you have no CHAR types in your table, so I'd skip the COLLATE anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with `wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php` path 
I improve your existing code, tested

```
function activate_cron() {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'fbcron';
    //check if table exist
    if($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table_name';") != $table_name) {      
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE ".$table_name." (
        id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        post_id int(11) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
        ) ".$charset_collate.";";

        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php'); //this path
        dbDelta($sql);
        }
    }

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'activate_cron' );
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I don't know why it's not working on your plugin.. i try this and working on my localhost.. you may try deactivated and try activate it again..